# Regular expression replace double and single quotes with nothing

Tags: regex, sphinx

I am using a sphinx search module on a site I am developing and there is the option to enter regular expressions to be replaced with specified characters.

The available options are `Match Expression`,`Replace Expression` and `Replace Char` (these are input fields in a CMS admin panel so I'm unsure of the actual code function used behind the scenes unfortunately). My understanding is the search checks for any expressions which match `Match Expression` and replaces the expressions specified in `Replace Expression` with those specified in `Replace Char`. So it's a sort of find and replace on matched terms.

Some examples that work:

*Example 1*

**Match Expression:** `/[a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*/`

**Replace Expression:** `/-/`

**Replace Char:** empty

Matched text: `SX500-123`, `GLX-11A`, `GLZX-VXV`, `GLZ/123`, `GLZV 123`, `CNC-PWR1`

Result text: `SX500123`, `GLX11A`, `GLZXVXV`, `GLZ/123`, `GLZV-123-123`, `CNCPWR1`

*More examples here:* http://mirasvit.com/doc/ssp/2.3.2/ssp/global/long_tail

---

What I want to do is strip any single or double quotes or apostrophes from a search query.

Example inputs: `"examination papers"`,`'examination papers`,`'examination' "papers"`,`pa"pers`,`pa'pers`

Desired outputs: `examination papers`,`examination papers`,`papers`,`papers`,`papers`

I have tried just replacing the `-` with a `"` in the examples listed above for now but even this hasn't worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use these expressions:

**Match Expression** - `/["'][\w\s]+["']|\w+["']\w+/`

This will match the following text:

```
"examination papers",'examination papers','examination' "papers",pa"pers,pa'pers
```

Then you can use this regex to replace your quotes:

**Replace Expression** - `/["']/`

**Replace Char** - `empty`

So, your output will be:

```
examination papers,examination papers,examination papers,papers,papers
```

As a context for this answer. I understand from the tool you are using that your **match expression** gathers a resultset where you can apply another regex expression (**Replace expression**) that will replace the content matched with **replace char**

Comment: Is that what she puts in the Replace Expression, described in the question?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Robert, she copied/pasted an example from the page. I understood from her that `What I want to do is strip any single or double quotes or apostrophes from a search query`. Btw, she also put the input and the desired output. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I have just tried entering both ["'] and /["']/ in the Match Expression and Replace Expression fields, and this hasn't worked.

Comment: @Sarah The match expression is not going to change.  It's always going to be `/[a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*/`

Comment: @Fede: I just think we're missing something basic, since your answer seems obvious.

Comment: I think the fact that these are entries into a CMS admin panel instead of actual code isn't helping but the module files are beyond my understanding so I don't know where the actual code function that makes the replacement lies I'm afraid.

Comment: @RobertHarvey surely that match expression would only match expressions which contain a - ? I want to match anything which contains a single or double quote at the beginning or end of the term.

Comment: @Sarah: Didn't you say your example works for dashes?  Don't confuse the *match expression* with the *replace expression.*

Comment: @Sarah I have misunderstood your question. I updated my answer. I think that your match expression gathers a resultset where you can apply another regex expression that will replace the content with replace char

Comment: @RobertHarvey The example shown does work for dashes. I thought the example meant "find any phrase which matches `a-z,A-Z,0-9 THEN a dash THEN a-z,A-Z,0-9`(match exp), and replace the dashes in the phrase (replace exp) with nothing (replace char)." What I want is "find any phrase which contains a single or double quote, and replace the single or double quote with nothing". Perhaps my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  Have you tried Fede's approach posted above yet?

Comment: @Fede Thank you for your help but I am afraid the edited answer hasn't worked either.

Comment: @Sarah hmm... I don't see why it isn't working. Is it possible to have access to that tool? It is very specific so dealing with this is difficult unless I could try it

Comment: @Fede if you'd like you can go to the backend demo of the module (linked from here) http://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/magento-sphinx-search.html. The inputs I am entering are in Search (nav bar in back end) / Settings / Merge Settings (Long Tail)

Comment: @Fede actually that module is returning different results to me. If you search `so-ny` or `"sony"` on the demo you get the Sony product. On my site if you search for `so-ny` you get the Sony product but if you search for `"sony"` you get no results which is what I am trying to resolve. Sorry but I can't show you the actual site I am working on. I think the module demo is a more advanced version of the module I have.

Comment: @Sarah I took a look. It seems that my answer provided should work since this regex engine works as I thought. On Sphinx Search setting I can see the input fields you mentioned but I cannot provide input strings as sample data. So, I'm willing to help you but I have no way to test a online examples. IMHO I think you should post in Sphinx forum asking why my approach isn't working.

Comment: @Fede, yes I totally understand and I'm sorry I don't have that much information or a working example of my problem. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @Sarah my pleasure. Sorry couldn't help better